# Getting the DocumentChooserPanel in an admin view

Tags: wagtail

I have created a script that reads an Excel document, parses the data and creates and saves new `Page` instances within Wagtail.

I would like this script to run within the Wagtail admin when a user uploads an Excel sheet, chooses it via the `DocumentChooserPanel` and hits run.

I have followed the official [Wagtail hooks guide](http://docs.wagtail.io/en/v1.12.3/reference/hooks.html) to create the new admin view and hooked it up with a template which extends `wagtailadmin/base.html`. I am unsure how to go about calling the `DocumentChooserPanel` and displaying it within my template. I am also not totally sure how to work with the chosen document and make it interact with my script. Any pointers on how I should go about doing this? Or resources/tutorials I could use?

**wagtailadmin/data_upload.html**

```
{% extends "wagtailadmin/base.html" %}

{% block titletag %}Upload Data{% endblock %}

{% block content %}
<header class="merged nice-padding">
    <div class="row row-flush">
        <div class="col12">
            <h1>Data Upload Centre</h1>
            <h3>Upload data here based on Excel spreadsheet templates.</h3>
        </div>
    </div>
</header>
{% endblock %}
```

**wagtail_hooks.py**

```
@hooks.register('register_admin_menu_item')
def register_data_menu_item():
  return MenuItem('Data Upload', reverse('data_upload_view'), classnames='icon icon-code', order=10000)

def data_upload_view(request):
    template = "wagtailadmin/data_upload.html"
    context = {}
    return render(request, template, context)

@hooks.register('register_admin_urls')
def urlconf_time():
  return [
    url(r'^data-upload-centre/$', data_upload_view, name='data_upload_view'),
  ]
```

Comment: DocumentChooserPanel might not be the best fit here. As I understand, you don't need to save the document (with the chooser would do), just to process it. I think, a vanilla `FileField` field might be a better fit. The Django documentation has an example on how to do [basic file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

Comment: @LoïcTeixeira Thanks, this worked. Although I'm a bit puzzled - are these file uploads stored in memory and then deleted? Or are they saved somewhere?

Comment: According to the documentation, [it depends on the size of the file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).

Comment: I've now copied this to an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Copying as an answer the resolution found in the comments for clarity.*

`DocumentChooserPanel` might not be the best fit here. As I understand, you don't need to save the document (which the chooser does) but only to process it. I think, a vanilla `FileField` field might be a better fit. The Django documentation has an example on how to do [basic file upload](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#basic-file-uploads).

FWIW, depending on the file size, the document uploaded via the `FileField` will be [kept in memory or saved as a temporary file](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/http/file-uploads/#where-uploaded-data-is-stored).